# How to sort IEnumerable<FileInfo> testList?

Tags: c#, fileinfo

```
DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo("C:\Temp");
IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesList = dir.getFiles("*.zip", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);
```

I tried this with something like `testList.OrderBy(f=>f.Name)` but it doesn't work. It gives me an error.

Comment: What is the error you are getting? Also, please tag what language you are looking at. This let the question be seen by people who may know what you are after

Comment: Like LordBaconPants said if you provide a few more lines of code (preferably after the lines you quoted) it'll make it easier for a member to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

> I tried ... but it doesn't work. It gives me an error

You had the right idea, using `LINQ` and `OrderBy`, and likely experienced errors in some other part of your code. One likely culprit was the unescaped backslash in the path, where `@` or `\\` was needed.

The following block of code runs without error in Linqpad to filter and sort .txt files in my `c:\temp` folder. Changing `OrderBy` to `OrderByDescending` 
 reverses the results as expected.

```cs
void Main()
{
    DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Temp");
    IEnumerable<FileInfo> filesList = dir.GetFiles("*.txt", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly);

    // Iterate on the sorted set
    foreach(var fileInfo in filesList.OrderBy(fileInfo => fileInfo.Name))
    {
        Console.WriteLine(fileInfo.Name);
    }
}
```